# template class to class with template member

Tags: c++, templates

A class template like this

```
template <typename... T>
class Action {
private:        
    std::tuple<T...> m_args;
public:
    Action(T... args) : m_args(args...) {}
}
```

to a class with template member. The reason why doing this is want to make only one type of class, so that object with different args still belong to the same class for easy manipulation.

```
class Action {
private:       
    // this does not work, how to declare the tuple type so that It can hold any arguments list.
    template <typename... T>
    std::tuple<T...> m_args;
public:   
    template <typename... T>
    Action(T... args) : m_args(args...) {}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! In the future, please state your question in the text outside of your code snippets. It's easier for us to understand you.

Comment: impossible without type erasure techniques. Consider what is sizeof(Action)?

Comment: How about make the member m_args as a pointer to a variant tuple, how to declare that pointer then?

Comment: Type erasure. You'd have to use a void pointer. C++ is pretty straightforward in terms of needing to have types understood at compile time. This is part of why C++ is so stinkin' fast.

Comment: What about `std:any`?

Comment: @xskxzr what about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your mind in the perspective of the compiler. How would our trusty friend know how much storage is required for `Action`, if that size would be dependent upon what constructor was resolved? This is not possible.

```
template<typename... T>
Action(T... args) : m_args(args...) {}

// wait what???
Action(int someArg) : m_args(someArg) {}
```

Let's say the second constructor was valid, or we had two `Action` objects with different arguments passed into the constructor -- what should be `sizeof(Action)`?

If you get stuck on an issue like this, think as the compiler: there was probably some person who had to give a good enough reason why it shouldn't be supported, simply because it only complicates the implementation and also has performance implications.

---

Since you mentioned using a pointer instead of an aggregated object, I figured I'd show you how to do this for completeness. Do note that this has performance implications, because you are now allocating the memory for `m_args` on the heap, rather than the stack.

```
class Action
{
public:
    template<typename... T>
    using TArgs = std::tuple<T...>;

    std::shared_ptr<void> m_args;

    template<typename... T>
    Action(T... args) 
        : m_args(std::make_shared<TArgs<T...>>(args...)) {}
};

Action myAction(1, 2.0, 3.5f);

auto *myActionArgs = 
    static_cast<Action::TArgs<int, double, float>*>(myAction.m_args.get());

// 2.0
double secondArg = std::get<1>(*myActionArgs);
```

This does not look like fun to maintain.

Comment: Thank you. As the point m_args to some API functions which accept void *, how I can know which tuple type I should convert back to. I would not know the type is `static_cast<std::tuple<int, double, float>*>`

Comment: Can you give me more context to how you're using this? It seems like you're trying to do dynamic typing, which C++ is not the language for.

Comment: For example, you need pass different working thread functions to threadpool. On windows, pass the function with parameters through the second parameter `PVOID pv` of `CreateThreadpoolWork`. Then the CALLBACK need to unpack them and run that function with its parameters. `std::bind` might work for this case, but I would like to have generic solution to unpack the parameters myself.

Comment: You will not be able to accomplish this sanely with C++. You lose all information once you have a void pointer. There are literal hacks that you can do to inspect memory, but again, C++ wasn't designed for this.